# Как сделать проверку существования записи в sqlite3?

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Видел подобный вопрос, но не смог найти нужного ответа.

Задача:

При вызове функции `def scoreupdater(chatid)`, нужно создавать в таблице строчку вида `"'значение chatid' , 0 , 0 , 0"`

А затем обновлять значения этой строчки.

Сейчас моя функция выглядит так:

```
def scoreupdater(chatid):
   con = sqlite3.connect('statsbase.db')
   cursorObj = con.cursor()
   cursorObj.execute("INSERT INTO stats (fromuserid, statpl ,statmn, k) VALUES(?,0,0,0)", [chatid])
   cursorObj.execute("UPDATE stats SET statpl = statpl + 1 where fromuserid = ?" , [chatid])
   con.commit()
   con.close()`
```

Проще говоря, нужно добавить проверку над третьей строчкой функции, и если такое значение `chatid` уже где-то есть то игнорировать третью строчку. Так же знаю что можно задавать значения по умолчанию, но так и не понял как. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На будущее - используйте `ORM`. Рекомендую `SQLAlchemy`.
А так:

```
def is_chat_exists(chatid) -> bool:
   con = sqlite3.connect('statsbase.db')
   cursorObj = con.cursor()
   return bool(cursorObj.execute(f'SELECT * FROM stats WHERE chatid={chatid};').fetchall())
```

Ну и засунем в ваш код:

```
...
cursorObj = con.cursor()
if not is_chat_exists(chat_id):
    cursorObj.execute("INSERT INTO stats (fromuserid, statpl ,statmn, k) VALUES(?,0,0,0)", [chatid])
cursorObj.execute("UPDATE stats SET statpl = statpl + 1 where fromuserid = ?" , [chatid])
...
```

Comment: Да, то что нужно, а возможна ли реализация без функции?

Comment: Это будет некрасиво. Но можете прям в коде `if bool(cursorObj.execute(f'SELECT * FROM stats WHERE chatid={chatid};').fetchall()): ###`